# How do I split a number into chunks of max 100 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, integer

I have a number (let's say 525). I would like to take this number and split it into an array of chunks with a max of 100 each value. If I took `525` and split it into an array, it would look like:

```
[
    100,
    100,
    100,
    100,
    100,
    25
]
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var number = 525;
var array = [];
while (number > 0) {
    number = number - 100;
    array.push(Math.min(number, 100));
}
```

That doesn't get me far. It just returns `[ 100, 100, 100, 100, 25, -75 ]`. I know that using `while` isn't the best way to go, but that is what I could think of off the top of my head. Does anyone have any other way that improve my code and be more efficient?

Comment: Just swap the order of the 2 lines of code inside your `while` loop.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can figure the number of times that `number` is divisible by `100` then programmatically create an array of that length:

```
var number = 525;
var array = new Array(Math.floor(number / 100)).fill(100).concat(number % 100))
// [ 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 25 ]
```

You can extend this to chunk by any number:

```
function chunkBy(number, n) {
  var chunks = Array(Math.floor(number / n)).fill(n);
  var remainder = number % n;

  if (remainder > 0) {
    chunks.append(remainder);
  }
  return chunks;
}
```

Alternatively, simply push the element before performing your subtraction:

```
var number = 525;
var array = [];
while (number > 0) {
    array.push(Math.min(number, 100));
    number = number - 100;
}
// [ 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 25 ]
```

Using ES6 with arrow functions:

```
const chunkBy = (n) => number => {
  var chunks = new Array(Math.floor(number / n)).fill(n);
  var remainder = number % n;
  console.log('CHUNKS = ', chunks);
  if (remainder > 0) {
    chunks.push(remainder);
  }

  return chunks;
};

const chunkBy50 = chunkBy(50);
const chunkBy100 = chunkBy(100);
const chunkBy77 = chunkBy(77);
console.log(chunkBy50(500));
// [ 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50 ]
console.log(chunkBy100(500));
// [ 100, 100, 100, 100, 100 ]
console.log(chunkBy77(500));
// [ 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 38 ]
```

Comment: One problem in your answer is, what happens when the number is divisible by 0 - for example 500.

Comment: It would add an extra `0` on the end yes,

Answer (score 1):

You should move the line `number = number - 100;` after you push the number, so it will count the 1st 100, and stop before pushing the -75:

```js
var number = 525;
var array = [];
while (number > 0) {
  array.push(Math.min(number, 100));
  number = number - 100; // remove number after pushing
}

console.log(array);
```

And a fancy one using `Array#from`:

```js
const number = 525;

const get100s = (number) => Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(number / 100) }, (_, i) => {
  const leftover = number - i * 100;
  
  return leftover > 100 ? 100 : leftover;
});

console.log('525: ', get100s(525));
console.log('500: ', get100s(500));
console.log('10: ', get100s(10));
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly! I'll mark it as an answer as soon as Stack Overflow will let me.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use integer division to get the number of occurrences for the "max" divisor and then use the "mod" operation to get the final chunk or remainder.

```
const number = 525;
const max = 100;

const maxCount = Math.floor(number / max); // 5
const remainder = 525 % max; // 25
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are substracting 100 to the number after adding it to the array.

The code should be like this:

```
var number = 525;
var array = [];
while (number > 0) {
  array.push(Math.min(number, 100));
  number = number - 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I think completely different about this kind of problem.  I would have divided the number by the section size and rounded down/truncated to get the number of sections, added that many sections to the final array, and then added the modulus of the section size and the number as the final value.

```js
var value = 525;

function splitValue(val, sectionSize)
{
  var sections = Math.floor(val/sectionSize);
  var finalValue = val%sectionSize;
  var splitValues = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < sections; i++) {
    splitValues.push(sectionSize);
  }
  
  splitValues.push(finalValue);
  
  return splitValues;
}

var valueArray = splitValue(value, 100);

console.log(valueArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use modulus.

```
let x = 556;
let mod = 100; 
let res = [];
for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(x / mod); i++) res.push(mod);
res.push(x % mod);
```